# Possible causes for television switching on by itself

Tags: tv

I have an LG LCD television set that has served me well for about five years now. Only recently has it started acting really weird. All of a sudden it will turn on, when turned on it will go to menu and exit it and do several other things like display details of the program currently on.

The first thing I thought was that this might be due to some IR interference from the outside. But it seems like this is happening even with shutters closed or when the IR receiver is positioned towards the wall. My question is what else could be causing such behavior in a TV and if it be potentially fixable. I suspect that if it's a hardware problem, I will have a hard time finding someone diagnosing fixing and fixing the TV for a reasonable price, but of course I might be overlooking some trivial explanation. Please, advise.

Comment: Sounds like demonic posession, or maybe just a boggart has taken up residence.  Either way, this is not a electrical design issue for this site.

Comment: Have you at least opened the TV and got a look if there is something seriously wrong?

Comment: Does it always turn on for the same show? More seriously, have you installed any LED bulbs in the same room lately? They jam the remote on my stereo.

Comment: Have you spilled any beer on the buttons of the remote lately?

Comment: Possibly some wayward sales person snook into your flat and programmed the auto record menu to pop up the HSN.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the remote and/or the show running. Demonic posession also doesn't sound very likely. I have instaled LEDs in the same room a couple months ago, definitely well before these problems started. The reason I'm posting it here is that I thought some internal circuitry might be the culprit.

Comment: BTW it got worse and worse until I finally took it for servicing and it turned out the board was faulty. It's was old one, so fixing it would cost more than getting a new one. In the end we just disposed of it.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should try placing a piece of tape over the receiver - something good and opaque, like electrical tape. IR light can bounce just like any other light, and turning it to the wall may not be helping. If that actually helps, you may want to repeat the experiment by taping over the remote itself, to see if that's generating the problem.

If the tape solved the problem, look for sources of IR noise - did you replace a fluorescent lamp recently? Some of them can do weird things if the control signal needed is too simple.

If you don't live alone, look for someone screwing with you - some cell phones are equipped with IR blasters to be used in controlling electronics.

In all likelihood, if you aren't going to do this yourself, it may be time for a new TV - technology in consumer televisions has improved greatly in the last five years, resulting in lower prices and better performance.

Comment: I think I can safely rule out controller issue. Remember I even tried turning the TV screen side to the wall. I also put the remote safely out of IR reach. If it were somebody screwing with me (which I thought of), he'd have to be really patient - that has been going on for weeks.

Comment: This is a troubleshooting effort, and you have to rule things out. Tape over the TV receiver to rule out any external input problems - like I just said it could come from a light, in the same room. If it still happens, its internal and there may be a stray path or an IC malfunction.